# Guava Cache - When are the evicted items garbage collected? How is the behaviour different when we use weakValues?

Tags: java, guava

I've a use case where I want a time-bounded map with expiring entries for which I'm using Guava Cache. The application is run inside a container, and I've the following configuration for the cache - thus entries older than 5 secs expire or if the cache reach the defined size they are evicted (as I can see from the logs being printed from removal notifier). But the issue is the memory usage is ever-growing and is never freed up, my guess here is probably the entries have become eligible for GC but are not taken up yet.

```
CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
       .maximumSize(1000)
       .expireAfterWrite(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
       .removalListener(this::logEviction)
       .build()
```

So I wanted to understand when exactly does GC will happen after eviction? i.e. If an entry is expired and removed from the Cache, when will it be freed from memory?

Also when I use weakValues, I don't face this problem but I am see some values are evicted with cause as "COLLECTED" (while others are either "EXPIRED" or "SIZE", which means they were garbage collected as per documentation. What I want to understand here is, are they garbage collected even before other conditions were met (i.e. expiry time or maximum size)?

Comment: The Java GC does not necessarily run immediately when some memory region is reclaimable (i.e. no longer strongly referenced by anything). It's up to the GC when to run and there's relatively little you can do from application code to force it to run - it is suggested to tune the JVM if one has a certain GC behaviour in mind. That said, are you actually running into OOM errors?

Comment: No errors as such, but since the application is running on container the load grows on host which will impact other applications. Also at one instance the application got stuck which I suspect was due to memory.

Comment: Are you running Java >9? If so, the JVM will honor limits set on the container such as available memory (it did not in Java 8). One option would be to set the maximum memory that the container can use.

Comment: I'm using Java 8 only, I've limits set on the container but I expect my application to reach near 70% those limits during certain times, but due to these objects taking up the memory I worry the memory usage is more that even during regular usage, I'm worried what will happen at that time. It has failed once.

Comment: Do you have any idea on the second part of the question?

Comment: having issues with this as well. When I add objects to cache and overwrite it, it is not being garbage collected. When I create object and then null the variable holding then call   System.gc() it will get garbage collected immediately.